# Unable to upload data through sqlldr(Sql loader)

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm trying to upload data through sql loader but I'm not able to upload the data in oracle database I'm getting below error.

```
data test.csv

1,a,b,c,d,20150728
2,a1,b1,c1,d1,20150727
3,a2,b2,c2,d2,20150726
4,a3,b3,c3,d3,20150725
5,a4,b4,c4,d4,20150724
```

1st Method

```
load data
into table table_abc
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6 date 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Error

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table T_LLY_08135_20150302_001, column t6.
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

2nd Method

```
load data
into table table_abc
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6 date TO_DATE(t6,"MMDDYYYY"))
```

Error

```
SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 4.
Expecting "," or ")", found "TO_DATE".
t1,t2,t3,t4,t5, date TO_DATE(t6,"MMDDY
```

table structure

```
sqlplus> desc table_abc
    TABLE varchar2
     Name    Null?    Type                        
     --------- -------- ----------------------------
     t1      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)                  
     t2               varchar2(38)                  
     t3               varchar2(38)                  
     t4               varchar2(38)                  
     t5               VARCHAR2(400)
     t6               date
```

Answer (score 1):

try your first example but use double quotes

```
load data
into table table_abc
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6 date "YYYYMMDD")
```

Comment: thnks 4 ur reply I'm getting date like this 11-DEC-14 when I follow the above method